# Limit using L'Hopital Rule $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{3(1+x)^{1/3}-1}\right)^{\frac{x}{\sin^2x} } $

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit of

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+}  \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{3(1+x)^{1/3}-1}\right)^{\frac{x}{\sin^2x}  } $$

using L'Hopital rule.

I tried to rewrite the limit as

$$ \large e^{\ln\left(\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{3(1+x)^{1/3}-1}\right)^{\frac{x}{\sin^2x}  }   \right)} $$

$$ \large e^{\left(\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x}{\sin^2x} \ln \left( \frac{\ln(1+x)}{3(1+x)^{1/3}-1} \right)  \right)}   $$

$$  \large e^{\left(\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x\ln (\ln(1+x))-\ln(3(1+x)^{1/3}-1)}{\sin^2x}    \right)} $$

But after that it leads to another indeterminate form. Could someone help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$  \frac{\ln(1+x)}{3(1+x)^{1/3}-1} \to \frac 0 2=0$$

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+ }\frac{x}{\sin^2x} \stackrel{H.R.}=  \lim_{x\to 0^+ }\frac{1}{2\sin x\cos x}=\infty$$

therefore the given limit is equal to $0$ since $0^\infty$ it is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: What does H.R. stand for?

Comment: @VIVID It stands for Hopital's Rule! Of course we can avoid it by $ \frac{\sin x}x\to 1$.